# Clarification on .NET 5

Tags: .net-core, .net-5

I have gone through .NET 5 features and looks like everything is understandable but I have few points. Can anyone please correct my points that are listed below?

1. DOT NET 5 has a single CLR for both Framework and Core
2. DOT NET Standard is the way to share a library between the .NET framework and .NET core
3. As per the documentation, the .NET 5 is the next version of .NET Core. If we install .NET 5 on Linux, we can't create and run framework related projects on Linux because still, they are windows specific applications.
4. I think the backword compatibility from .NET 5/ .NET x to .NET Core 3.1/ .NET Core 2.1 will be possible if there are no breakage changes.
5. For .NET core 3.1, we can install the runtime and run the already built application. Is it the same case with .NET 5. we can just install the .NET runtime and run the .NET 5(Framework and Core) applications.

Answer (score 1):

1. [No, Framework and Core/5.0 have different CLRs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/glossaryclr)
2. Yes, .NET standard is effectively the bridge between Framework and Core/5.0. That said, Standard is effectively end-of-life (final version is 2.1) as Microsoft no longer wishes to support Framework going forward.
3. Yes. Framework applications are and always will be restricted to Windows only.
4. Yes.
5. No, you have never been able to execute Framework apps via a Core runtime or vice versa. You need the matching runtime for the type of application you are executing.